# How to create a texture SRV with different sRGB format from a render target in DX11?

Tags: textures, directx, sharpdx, srgb, stride

Is it possible to bind a texture with a different format as render target and as shader resource view?

Specifically with a different _SRGB suffix. My goal is to render a shader into an R8G8B8A8_UNORM texture but read the render target in another shader as R8G8B8A8_UNORM_SRGB, or the other way around. Basically controlling on the read and write side whether automatic sRGB conversion should happen. There is no window or swap chain involved.

So far, I get an invalid args exception when I try to create a texture view with a different format. I am using the Stride game engine set to Directx 11 graphics API, which uses SharpDX.

Comment: Try making the resource ``R8G8B8A8_TYPELESS`` and then create your RTV/SRV with the desired formats.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn yes, that was the solution! If you want to add that as a reply, I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct3D supports 'type re-casting' within limits.

You typically have to first create the resource as 'typeless' which in this case would be `DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_TYPELESS`:

```
CD3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc(
        DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_TYPELESS,
        width, height,
        1, // The render target view has only one texture.
        1, // Use a single mipmap level.
        D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET | D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE,
        D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT,
        0,
        1
    );

DX::ThrowIfFailed(device->CreateTexture2D(
    &desc,
    nullptr,
    &m_renderTarget));
```

Create the RTV as `DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM`:

```
CD3D11_RENDER_TARGET_VIEW_DESC rtvDesc(
    D3D11_RTV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D,
    DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM);

DX::ThrowIfFailed(device->CreateRenderTargetView(
        m_renderTarget.Get(),
        &rtvDesc,
        &m_renderTargetView));
```

Then create the SRV as `DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM_SRGB`:

```
CD3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC srvDesc(
    D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D,
    DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM_SRGB);

DX::ThrowIfFailed(device->CreateShaderResourceView(
    m_renderTarget.Get(),
    &srvDesc,
    &m_shaderResourceView));
```

> Note that there are some special conditions when using SRGB for backbuffers. See [this blog post series](https://walbourn.github.io/care-and-feeding-of-modern-swapchains/).

Comment: Excellent, this works perfectly, thanks!